# How to import .C & .pl extension exploits into metasploit framework?

Tags: exploit, metasploit

How can i import .C(c language) and .Pl(perl) extension module exploits into the Metasploit framework?
Metasploit generally accept the .rb (ruby) extension modules?

Can anyone provide tutorials to import these extension modules? I read about the immunity debugger, but I don't understand the way to convert it. Immunity debugger is used to code exploits.

I just want to import the below shellcode in metasploit framework.This code is written in C language. So is there any way to import the below exploit into metasploit framework.

http://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/1/

Answer (score 0):

There is No Sofware Or Tool which can convert the exploit from C/C++ or the others into the metasploit framework, it's easy and you can do it with learning some essentials of ruby. then take a note of important values from the exploit and put the values in the metasploit's exploit frame. values such as Return Address, EIP and the buffer size is required, no need to include the payload.